# I can't make the validation rule

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'd like to check the value only when the value isn't NULL.

```
$validator->add('sort_order', 'valid', [
    'rule' => 'numeric',
    'message' => Configure::read('errorMessage.numericOnly'),
    'on' => function ($context) {
        return !empty($context['data']['sort_order']);
    }
]);
```

I try this code but it didn't work.

`"This field cannot be left empty"` <- this message is shown when the value is NULL.

Where is it wrong?

```
$validator
    ->add('sort_order', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric', 'message' => 'numericOnly'])
    ->allowEmpty('sort_order');
```

I also try this.
It didn't work.
Error message isn't shown when I enter the non-numeric value.

Comment: I would suspect that the message stems from a different rule, most likely `notEmpty` or `allowEmpty`. Please show all the rules that do apply to your field.

Comment: I don't have anything else. i try with `allowEmpty`

Comment: In that case your validator might not be used at all. Do you have multiple validators? Are you requesting to use a specific validator in your `newEntity/patchEntity` calls?

Comment: multiple validators...? maybe I have single validator only. Do I need write `['validate' => false]` at `newEntity` call?

Comment: No, you only need to use that option at all if you'd wanted to specifiy a non-`default` validator (`validationDefault()`). That's what I was referring to, whether you have multiple validators, ie non-default ones. What you are showing in the second example, should (and actually does) work just fine.

Comment: If I use the second example, it works when the value is NULL. But error message isn't shown when I enter the non-numeric value.

Comment: I must correct myself, my first comment is wrong, or at least misleading, I mixed up presence and emptyness, the former is allowed by default, the latter isn't. So the empty message is actually correct, however using `allowEmpty()` should fix that. The message for a non-numeric value is shown just fine for me. What value exactly is being passing to the entity creation/patching process?

Comment: `What value exactly is being passing to the entity creation/patching process?` -> non-numeric value(ex. 'qqq' , 'abc'). It may not be relationship, its non-numeric value register as 0 to DB. I configure the default value is 0.

Comment: It should work fine in that case. You'll need to show some more code (controller, view) and debug this further (what exactly does the marshaller pass to the validator), at this point all I could do is shooting into the dark, which isn't overly useful.